# Properly plotting on Grafana from Elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana, opensearch, grafana-variable

I wan to plot a time series on Grafana from some documents stored in ElasticSearch. The documents are structured as follows:

```
{
    "timestamp": date,
    "name1": str,
    "name2": str,
    "number": float
 }
```

Since for a given a value of `name1` only certain values of `name2` are possible, I set up two variables on Grafana:

```
Name1: {"find": "terms", "field":"name1.keyword"}
Name2: {"find":"terms", "field":"name2.keyword", "query":"name1:$Name1"}
```

These two variables correctly generate two drop-down menus that I can use to select the proper value of `name2` given a value of `name1`. Now, after selecting a given value of `name1` and `name2` in the menus I would like Grafana to plot the time series of `number` corresponding to that (unique) combination of `name1` and `name2`, and I'm trying to do it through the following query:

```
name1:$Name1 AND name2:$Name2
```

selecting `Group By: Date Histgram` and `timestamp` as the time axis. Problem is, this does not work properly unless I have only one single value of `name2` for each `name1`, and let me explain why via an example. Suppose I have these two documents:

```
{
    "timestamp": 20220110,
    "name1": "foo",
    "name2": "bar",
    "number": 2.0
 }

{
    "timestamp": 20220110,
    "name1": "foo",
    "name2": "tee",
    "number": 3.0
 }
```

and that I choose `max` as metric. In that case, no matter what I select in the `name2` drop down menu, Grafana will always plot a point `(20220110, 3)`, where 3 corresponds to the maximum between 2 and 3. I understand the reason of this behavior: what I do not understand is how to obtain what I want. So: How can I change my query in such a way that, selecting `bar` in the `name2` drop down menu I get a point `(20220110, 2)`, and if instead I select `tee` from the same menu I obtain `(20220110, 3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I figured out the solution. So, the behavior was not supposed to be the one I described above, and the reason is that `name2` was usually using `-` characters in the string, which were poorly interpreted by the Lucene query. The only safe way to proceed in this case is by writing the variables in this way:

```
Name1: {"find": "terms", "field":"name1.keyword"}
Name2: {"find":"terms", "field":"name2.keyword", "query":"name1.keyword:$Name1"}
```

and the corresponding Lucene query as

```
name1.keyword:$Name1 AND name2.keyword:$Name2
```

This works as expected.